# Excel Generate Sequence Using Specified Format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

How to generate sequence numbers from 00.0000 to 99.9999 in excel?

E.g.

```
00.0000
01.0001
01.0002
----

99.9999
```

Update

```
Sub test()
[A1:A100000000] = [index((row(1:10000000)-1)/100000,)]
[A1:A100000000].NumberFormat = "00.000000"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify the reason for the downvote

Comment: Put the first two in two cells, highlight both the click on the lower right corner and drag down 1 million rows.

Comment: put 0 in the first cell and run this line in a sub: `[A2:A990000] = [index(1 + row(1:989999)/10000,)]`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I presume you're getting downvotes because you've not shared your research and what you've tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @ScottCraner Was looking for a solution with formula rather than dragging to a million rows. Honestly, have not understood `[A2:A990000] = [index(1 + row(1:989999)/10000,)]`

Comment: @Chks - If you don't want to drag down the rows, you'll need VBA, which is what ScottCraner posted.

Comment: It is vba.  A formula will need to be dragged down just like fill.  But you can put the first two in and use autofill, it is on  the home tab under Fill.

Comment: What's the sequence? The first increment (1.0001) is different is different from the second (0.0001).

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want to handle a spreadsheet with a million rows? That's database territory.

Comment: @Tetsujin former company CFO worked with a dump from our ERP database that was nearly a million rows on a daily basis. It WAS a database, but he wanted to work on it in Excel because that's what he was familiar with, and Excel does a decent job charting and getting basic BI from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for vba:

```
Sub test()
[A1:A1000000] = [index((row(1:1000000)-1)/10000,)]
[A1:A1000000].NumberFormat = "00.0000"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code runs very quickly!

Comment: (I know I know this ...) - why are you evaluating the ranges too?  Any difference in that than using `Range("A1:A10000")`?

Comment: Thanks for this. I do have the range, changed from `00.000000` to `99.999999` which resulted in `#VALUE!`

Comment: @BruceWayne It is just short hand for Range.  I only use it in this type of circumstance.

Comment: @Chks what exactly did you change it to.  This code will fill column A with the numbers from `00.0000` to `99.9999`  there is no need to change anything but the `[A1:A1000000]` to the column you want.  You need 1 million cells to hold the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner Modified the question to include modified version.

Comment: @Chks you have way too many `0` in your ranges.  You can not go to that detail.  There are only 1,048,576 rows and as such you can only go to 6 significant digits.  Your question has only 6, and now you want to change to 8.  If you had asked about 8 in your question, the answer would have been it is not possible.  This answers the question you originally asked, changing the scope of the question after getting answers is not proper on this site.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry for changing the range.

Comment: @ScottCraner Would it be possible to have it in multiple sheets if the limit reaches 1,048,576?

Comment: That is a new question, and should get its own post.  This answered the original question and should be marked as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  but be aware that just asking a question without trying to solve it yourself and showing what you have tried is also frowned on in this forum, which is why you got so many downvotes.  I answered only because it was a simple code.  The code you are asking for is more complicated. @Chks

Comment: @ScottCraner Sure will keep this in mind.